# When I am given multiple CSS files, should I just dump all the styles in my main application.css?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I work with front-end designers that give me a bunch of HTML & CSS files. There are some things that are very straight forward - like CSS for Twitter Bootstrap or any other framework.

But when the designer has created a bunch of other stylesheets, should I just include them in the stylesheets directory or should I just copy all the styles to the main `application.css` file?

Is this just a matter of style or does my approach really (or not) matter with the asset pipeline?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach doesn't usually matter, but it can matter if you do not want to include everything in one stylesheet link on the final page. I'd strongly recommend keeping the stylesheets separated for the same reason you keep code separated. Easier maintenance, less conceptual overhead per file, and easier to find where to make the change you need to make.

Even though they get combined by the asset pipeline, I tend to do one stylesheet per controller, or component, with certain shared styles (navigation, forms, common UI forms) in their own file. I haven't found the perfect solution yet (I still struggle with wanting "DRYer" stylesheets), but this works pretty well.

Comment: Well....as far as I understand it, the asset pipeline precompiles all the stylesheets into the `application.css` - so 2 dozen css files become 1 for production. I am just wondering how to organize it, on the dev side, aside from having stylesheets for each model/controller. That I already have, but then things like navigation - create a stylesheet just for navigation?

Comment: Yep, exactly. `application.css` is used as a manifest for compilation. However, you can choose to not include files into `application.css`, or to reference stylesheets outside of it. Hence the "it can matter if you do not want to include...". For things like navigation, that would fall under my "shared styles" section, and be a separate stylesheet that is `require`d into `application.css`

Answer (score 1):

`application.css` is ment to organize css file, i remember there are comments on the top of the `application.css` telling not to directly write css file inside it. You should create a new css file for those style-sheet content your front-end guy gave you. And as application.css will include all the files under the stylestheet folder automatically. It will work.

Comment: So styles that apply to my entire app....where do I put those...if not in the `application.css.scss`?

Comment: Then you can just create a file called `app.css` or whatever you like. And put all your stylesheet content into it. Then `application.css` will import it for you. And remember to call `<%=javascript_incude_tag :default%>` in your view.

Comment: What does the `:default` flag on that `js_include_tag` do? I disagree with the `app.css`. In fact, just checked my `application.css.scss` and it has this at the top: `You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.` I never saw that before...so I guess that answers that.

Comment: `:default` will include all css files that application.css imported. That will also mean all of them in other words. Unless you can just import the ones you want, `<%=javascript_include_tag 'file.which.you.created'%>`,ie.

Comment: I was under the impression that by including this: `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`, that covered all JS files - just like the CSS equivalent covered all CSS files...no?